# I have 2 button (Register Now) for CiviEvent

Tags: wordpress, civievent, registration, online-registration

I would like to add Events and Also website user and the public user could register for events. 
The problem is registration part: I have two registers now button on event page? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Two "Register Now" buttons is by design.

When you add more info to the event such as a formatted description, a picture,  a location map etc then the page can get quite large so the idea is that your users can easily get to a 'Register' button at the top and bottom of the page with minimal scrolling.

If you really don't want both buttons you can customise the event display.  See various answers here on SE such as [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/14667/225)

===
(Years later ...!)

One option is to go to `Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs`, in 'Custom CSS URL' enter `[civicrm.files]/css/extra.css`.
Then create your `extra.css` file with the following content:

```
div.register_link-top {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the event doesn't have more details how can we manage two buttons?

Comment: What do you mean by 'manage' two buttons?   Do you want to hide one of them?

Comment: yes If it's possible I want to hide one of them